# Get four cornermost points from list of coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates

Currently, I'm working on a model used for text recognition.

The model outputs a sequence of coordinates, which illustrated as this [in the paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ECCV_2018/html/Curtis_Wigington_Start_Follow_Read_ECCV_2018_paper.html) (the outputs are coords on pink and green points)

[image: sfr-lf]

The model output is a list of coordinates (can be in generic list or `numpy.ndarray`) of size `(n, 2)` with `n` as total bounding boxes detected.

Since the model produces a lot of coords for each bounding boxes, I want to extract 4 cornermost points from a single detected sequence to save memory for storing the data.

How can I extract this 4 points given the list of coords?

Comment: The question is *How do you want to extract these 4 cornermost* ?

Comment: Pardon? I'm assuming that most of the detected bboxes will be horizontal so it could be extracted by finding top/bottom/right/leftmost coords. But after trying with this approach, it seems that not every bboxes could be applied with this